# How to store order history in database, especially old picture paths?

Tags: database

[image]
***(table: order_items)***

I'm not sure if this is the correct way to implement an order history table in my database. Normally, I'm trying to reduce the redundancy. But because the user can **change data** in his/her offer, I need to save the **minimum information** of the order.

**Goal:** Buyer can see his/her old orders with correct title/pictures/origin path/allergens (long story...)

What speaks against my approach?

The only "fear" is that the table is going to be bloated with a lot of redundancy information.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This started out as a comment but it's getting too long, so...

What database are you working with?

SQL Server, for instance, introduced the concept of [temporal tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-2017) in 2016 version. Basically you have two tables identical in structure, where one is the main table where you can use DML just as you would with normal table, and the other is a readonly table that's storing the historical data - so when you update a record in the main table, what is actually happening is that the record gets copied into the history table first, and updated later.

Something similar might exists in other databases as well, and can also be quite easily manually implemented using triggers in case your database does not provide it out of the box.

Of course, you could use the technique called "soft delete", where instead of actually deleting the data you simply mark it as deleted, and instead of updating the data you create a new record with the updated data, and change the status of the existing record to Inactive.
The major advantage of this approach over temporal tables is that you still only have one table for your entity instead of two - but on the other hand, the advantage of temporal tables is that the active data is being kept in a separate table from the historical data, therefor the active data is stored in a relatively small table and as a result, all CRUD operations is more efficient.

The "fear" of having a bloated table in this day and age when memory and storage are so cheep seems a bit strange to me.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot! I'm using MySQL. And thank you for the link. Very interesting! And your very last sentence was important to me!

Comment: Glad to help :-). I don't know if MySql has support of temporal tables, but as I wrote - it's pretty easy to implement yourself using triggers (Assuming you know your way around SQL)